# Is there a uniform compiler error view in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio

Starting with Android Studio 3, the Messages view seems to have been removed. Majority of my code base is C++ integrated with Gradle. I would like a simple list of compiler errors that I can view after each build, similar to the Error List in Visual Studio. Right now I am using the "Build" tab which is a hot mess:

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a better mechanism to view and correct compiler errors (either Java or C++) in Android Studio 3.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are still there:

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Messages
```

or

```
⌘ + 0
```

[image]

Comment: Wrong. What version of Android Studio are you running? I'm running 3.1 RC2

Comment: 3.0.1. Although I just found out that it depends on the project. In one (new project) I don't see messages in their old place.

Comment: Ah, it's all simple - just click `rebuild project`, then it will appear again. So basically when there are no `messages`, `messages` not available.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, although this doesn't ultimately help the main question I asked, which is how to view errors in a central place. If indirectly this means the Messages view, then that's fine. But Messages isn't showing when I'm able to build and obviously compiler errors are present.

Comment: It shows for me and everyone compilation errors. Try to reinstall your Android Studio then.